# Linearisation of non-linear models

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to linearise the following model:

$$y=\alpha xe^{\beta x}$$

I know I have to find an equation along the lines of $Y= A+BX$, but when I apply natural logarithms and use identities I still don't get quite an answer. This is what I got:

$$\ln{y}=\ln{\alpha}+\ln{x}+\beta x$$

I'm not sure how to proceed next. I thought maybe simply graphing $\ln{x}$ vs $\ln{y}$ would be alright but that extra $\ln{x}$ makes me doubt.

Comment: Linearize can also mean find a linear approximation. Which course is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $x,y > 0$ you can rewrite the model as
$$y=\alpha xe^{\beta x}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{y}{x}=\alpha e^{\beta x}$$
$$\Longrightarrow \ln\frac{y}{x}=\ln \alpha + \beta x$$
with $Y=\ln\frac{y}{x}, \;\; X=x.$