# Is it Possible to Linearise the Bounded Growth Model to use LLSQ?

Tags: numerical-methods, exponential-function, nonlinear-optimization, mathematical-modeling, least-squares

At the moment I try to find the best (easiest) way to fit the bounded growth model

$$ y_i = a-ae^{bx_i},$$

with parameter $a,b∈ℝ$, and data points $(x_i,y_i)$.  (This form is already simplified, such that the growth starts with $y(0)=0$.)

That model is non-linear, so the first way is to use Non-Linear Least Squares. 
Sometimes, like in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996722/linearisation-of-non-linear-models) it is possible to linearise the model function by using the logarithm. Then you can use Linear Least-Squares to fit the model.

I have tried that, but failed, because of the first summand $a-[...]$.

Is there a way to linearise this model?

---

Context: 
The data looks like this

[image]

The value $y_i$ will rise and follow the bounded growth model, see red box. The goal is to estimate the bound of that growth, i.e. the purple horizontal line. That is the parameter $a$ in the model. 
If that is lower/higher than the desired bound, you change system-parameters to achieve the desired bound. 
In the picture you can see two corrections done to the system.

Any help is appreciated. Also hints to literature are very welcome, as I couldn't find much on that topic. Which surprised me, as I thought that this is some kind of standard growth model.

edit: One way I found is using differentiation on the problem and then use the logarithm resulting in $$\ln(y_i') = \ln(a)+\ln(b)+bx_i,$$
but differentiating measured data is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model being $$y = a(1-e^{bx})$$ in a first step fix $b$ at a given value and define $z_i=1-e^{bx_i}$. So, a very simple linear regression gives $$a=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_iz_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^2}$$ Now, compute the sum of squares for this given value of $b$. Run a few cases and plot the results. When you see more or less a minimum, you have an estimate of $a,b$ and you can start the nonlinear regression.

But, there is no way to make the model linear (except if you know one of the parameters).

**Edit**

If you have a good estimate of $a$, then write $$\log \left(\frac{a-y}{a}\right)=bx$$ Define $z_i=\log \left(\frac{a-y_i}{a}\right)$ so the model is $z=b x$ and use $$b=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_iz_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't tried that yet, since I do have a good estimate for $a$, because that is the goal/bound of the growth function.  Are there any formula to get a good starting value of $b$?  Currently I set it to $-1$, as it will be something between $-1$ and $-0.001$, and the Levenberg-Marquardt Algorthmus that I use converges more stable if $b_{guess}<b$.

Comment: Let me edit my answer

Comment: Thank you!  (answer has to be greater n chars - hence the words in brackets)

Comment: @P.Siehr. You are very welcome ! Good luck in your work.

Comment: @P.Siehr. You do not need **at all** a Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: Why? The problem I want to fit is non-linear, and LM does fit non-linear functions. Another reason is, that there are several packages that use it, so I can compare my solution.

Comment: @P.Siehr. We can almost do it by hand. Consider Newton-Raphson for example. The problem in fact reduces to a single equation in $b$ for which you want the zero of..

Comment: To clarify things: Are you referring to the original fit-problem of my question, or the two methods you suggested in your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64337/discussion-between-claude-leibovici-and-p-siehr).